# Using Route::match() Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

Is it unconventional and therefore ill-advised to use the `match()` method to determine which controller method to use under 1 uniformed named route? I have this code:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/add/lecture/{course}', [
    'as' => 'addLecture',
    'uses' => Request::isMethod('post') ? 'Main@addLecture':'Main@showAddLecture'
]);
```

Which works as expected. But I just want to know if this is a feasible solution, or if I should stop being lazy and create two separate routes (I am not using `Route::resource()` for a particular reason, so please don't advise me to use that for basic CRUD). I don't mean for this question to be subjective, I presume there is an objective reason as to why this isn't employed very often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like hack. It's not readable and can stop working after random minor Laravel update. In my opinion it's better to create two explicit routes.

Comment: It looking like a 'hack' was my interpretation as well... Why would minor updates affect this though? It seems unlikely Laravel is going to change the parameters for the Route class any time soon, and if they did I wouldn't consider that a 'minor' change. I'll stick to two explicit routes though, just to be safe (and definitely improve readability). Thanks

Comment: Well, they did similar changes many times already and sometimes they even didn't tell about it.